# ArangoDB Query List for Strings

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, aql, nosql

I am relatively new to ArangoDB, and after reading through the docs am trying to implement it for a new project.

I have a collection of documents, and in each document is a list, which contains a number of terms. I am using the java driver, and would like to query for documents whose list matches any of the elements in the list I have.

Example:

```
Document 1
{
    tokens["blue", "red", "green"]
}

Document 2
{
    tokens["black", "red", "yellow"]
}

myArrayList:
["purple", "red"]
```

Since the ArrayList I am trying to query using contains the word "red", I should be presented with both document 1 and document 2. Ideally, I will only be presented with the document ID and the color that matches.

In half-psuedocode from what I know of AQL:

```
FOR document IN documents FILTER document.tokens CONTAINS myArrayList RETURN document.token.color && document._id
```

I normally have been returning the whole document object and then just accessing whatever I need. I could do that if it is easier. Eg:

```
FOR document IN documents FILTER document.tokens CONTAINS myArrayList RETURN document
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using the `IN` operator for filtering as follows:

```
FOR document IN documents
  FILTER document.tokens IN @myArrayList
  RETURN document
```

This will only return a document if the `tokens` attribute is an array and contains any of the values contained in the `@myArrayList` bind parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to my question on the ArangoDB Google Group. I am linking to it as it was very difficult for me to locate a solution: h[ttps://groups.google.com/forum/#!newtopic/arangodb/arangodb/fen4Nr7N4Uo](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!newtopic/arangodb/arangodb/fen4Nr7N4Uo)

I have adapted the code there to work for my case: (Credit to stj's comment for fixing what I wrote)

```
FOR document IN documents LET contains = 
(FOR color IN document.tokens FILTER MATCHES(color, @myArrayList) RETURN color)
FILTER LENGTH(contains) > 0 RETURN document
```

Comment: This query above will fail with parse errors. The parentheses do not match, and if there is a subquery, there should be an separate return statement contained in it. Apart from that, if does not filter out documents that do not contain any of the colors. I think it should look like this: `FOR document IN documents LET contains = (FOR color IN document.tokens FILTER MATCHES(color, @myArrayList) RETURN color) FILTER LENGTH(contains) > 0 RETURN document`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find documents, which at least contain all specified colors, in any order, you can use a query like this:

```
LET lenArrayList = LENGTH(@myArrayList)

FOR doc IN documents
    FILTER HAS(doc, "tokens") // avoid bad calls to INTERSECTION()
    FILTER LENGTH(INTERSECTION(@myArrayList, doc.tokens)) == lenArrayList
    RETURN doc
```

myArrayList: `["yellow","red"]`

Result: document 2, because it contains red and yellow.